# Certificate Errors with bad Date Time settings

Tags: certificate, internet-explorer

I have recently solved an issue with IE 11 where I was getting certificate errors to google.com

bing.com was fine no problems

I tried a number of different things till seeing a post referring to checking your date time settings. So I checked this and lo and behold they were out, and updating them solved the issue. But I am so confused. It is using the *SAME* certificate, so why did IE 11 block me with certificate error when the date time settings are out?

**EDIT**: When I say same certificate, I mean the same certificate was used for **google** before and after I updated the Date Time settings.

The expiry date of the cert was some time in 2022 and my Date Time settings were 20 or so days earlier not later so the answer below I don't think is correct.

Grateful any help!

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

If you check the Google certificate details, you will notice that there is an entry named "Not Valid Before: xxxx".

In this case, the value is November 20th. If your computer time was set before November 20th, the certificate would not be valid and you would get the mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say Google's certificate expires on 01/01/2015 and Bing's certificate on 01/01/2016.

If you set your clock to 07/01/2015 you will get an error (certificate expired) when accessing Google, and will not when accessing Bing.

They don't use the same certificate, each one have their own certificate.

Comment: I realize obviously different websites use different certificates. Bing was not using the Geotrust cert. I meant same certificate for google before and after the date change. That makes sense, except the expiry was 5/21/2022 (for the GeoTrust cert) and I was only like 20 days in the past. So i'm still confused on this one.